# Uncaught SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I am using Ruby on Rails.

### create.js.erb

```
$('#my_re_ap').html('<%= recaptcha_element('signup')%>');
```

but I am getting a `Uncaught SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break` error.

My view helper looks like this.  I am using the recaptcha gem.

### helper

```
  def recaptcha_element(event_name)
    if @show_checkbox_recaptcha
      content_tag :div, class: "pb-2" do
        recaptcha_tags
      end
    else
      recaptcha_v3(action: event_name, site_key: 'key123')
    end
  end
```

What is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: If your Ruby code produces a string with a line break, it will result in invalid JavaScript syntax. (And, apparently, that is happening.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could resolve it in 3 ways, using template literal or escape the single quote character

```js
console.log(`<%= recaptcha_element('signup')%>`);

console.log("<%= recaptcha_element('signup')%>");

console.log('<%= recaptcha_element(\'signup\')%>');
```